# html div not getting mouseclick when overlapped on image with higher z-index

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me out, I am not receiving onclick event (or most of mouse events) with IE8+
when I overlap in space "div" above "image". My html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>div home</title>



 <script type="text/javascript" >



function doRaise()
{
alert("hiii")   
}


</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="dragMe" onclick="doRaise()" style="position:absolute ;width: 50px; height:       50px;z-index: 100;border: solid red 2px"></div>
    <div>
    <img src="snap2.jpg" alt="no" />
    </div>
    welcome!!
</body>
</html>
```

But the same works good in case of Mozilla Firefox 12+ and Google Chrome latest version.

Please any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.
Prasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i make it out as below:
Thanks for help friends , thank you all 
    
     
        
        
        div home

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >



    function doRaise()
    {
         alert("hiii")   
    }


    </script>
```

```
<body>
    <div id="dragMe" onclick="doRaise()" 
style="position:absolute ;width: 50px; height:50px;z-index: 100;
        border: solid red 2px;
        background: transparent url(whatever.png)"></div>
    <div>
    <img src="snap2.jpg" alt="no" />
    </div>
        welcome!!
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another IE issue.
Try adding any background to the div (image or color).

you can use this if you want a transparent background:

```
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: ie8 doesn't support rgba(part of css3), but what you can use `background-color: rgb(0,0,0)` and then `filter: alpha(opacity=0);` w/c will make the div totally invisible (including the border)

Comment: you are right but not what i wanted, still thanks for the help

Comment: as background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) fails on IE8 as it is css3; i try to use background-image:url(black50.png); it worked but anyone could explain me this bit in detail

Answer (score 0):

Set background for 'div'. Try This css

`#dragMe{
         position:absolute ;width: 50px; height:  50px;z-index: 100;border: solid red 2px; 
         background: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* default color if rgba not supported*/
         background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01); padding: 4px; padding: 4px;
    }`

Comment: problem is i want to show background also it's hiding part of image Bob

Comment: or otherwise i have to restrict to IE9

Answer (score 0):

I did this through fiddle. Please check, hope this will help for your requirement..

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAuAc/1/)

Comment: problem is opacity=0, makes border also invisible so it's not aligned with my requirement, i want to see the border with transparent background right now i have to rely on rgba(0,0,0,0) which is css3 or transparent url(..) as background img